# After restarting, Intelli-J shows no Errors until I compile, and then 100 Errors

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am trying to use several modules written by a co-worker of mine (who is currently on vacation). I know the modules are working, because my code that relied on them was ALSO working.

But my computer had to restart after it froze up, and now when I go into my code everything is broken, and it appears that Intelli-J forgot my dependencies.

After a lot of fiddling, I decided to recheck everything out from git, reimport all the modules, etc. etc. But it isn't helping.

For example, "Error:(123, 15) java: package MPD does not exist" is one error I am getting, but I can jump to the line calling MPD and "go to declaration" and see it just fine! Intelli-J knows where the source is, and there is no red squiggly line indicating there's a problem in the editor itself.

What on earth is going on?  Did I somehow forget a step in importing modules (I imported them the same way, I thought, and added their dependencies wherever the editor said I needed to).   Or is Intelli-J itself somehow corrupted after that restart? How can I fix this?  I'm on day 2 of banging my head on this problem....

**Edit:** My current checkout from git has at least progressed a bit.  It turns out all my manual imports were incorrectly labelling the source as a "resource".  Manually setting most modules to correctly label "source" has gotten me further. Now I just have to figure out why it doesn't know what JUnit is anymore.  "Error:(3, 1) java: package junit.framework does not exist".  There's a few packages I haven't labeled as source yet, though, so maybe that'll fix it.

**Edit:**  Nope, labeling everything correctly as "source" or even "test" doesn't change my errors at all.  I can confirm that the Editor knows where the source for the various JUnit stuff, like TestCase, but the compiler swears up and down it doesn't exist. Different error, same flavor.  The JUnit references live in one of the modules, and I can confirm that if I do "mvn install" from the command line for that module, it compiles just fine.

**Edit:**  I can SEE Junit 3.8.1 and 4.4 in my library list, and the jar file exists where it says it should.

**Edit:** Different Java versions (oracle 7 vs 1.7 open jdk) do nothing.  I also tried excluding all the tests from compilation (at this point I'm desperate), but I seem to have to do it one at a time and there are a LOT of them, so I've given up that angle of attack.

**Edit:** Invalidating the caches and restarting does nothing at all, still getting the JUnit error.

**Edit:**  *sigh*  I excluded every single JUnit based class from compilation, finally.  And now I have gone full circle: "Error:(34, 15) java: package MPD does not exist".   So marking the files as source wasn't a real fix, it just delayed or hid the compilation errors.  I'm running out of random stuff to try....

**Edit:** I've nuked it from orbit again and got a fresh copy of my project and marked the things as source that gets me past the first compiler errors.  This time, I looked around in the dependency list, and saw that Junit was listed as only being "test" and not "compile".  Okay, I'll mark it as "compile" in all of these dozens of projects and see what happens. It is definitely getting rid of the Junit errors, one by one.

Comment: You.need to set up IntelliJ properly. Start from the beginning and and work your way carefully from project to artifact. The problem isn't IntelliJ; it's your project setup.

Comment: Okay, good to know Intelli-J isn't broken, but this apparently means I have forgotten how to set up Intelli-J correctly.  I'm importing the modules, I'm setting the dependencies...what am I missing? What specifically could cause a disconnect between the Editor and the Compiler?

Comment: Which version of IntelliJ?  Current is 14.1. I'm guessing that libraries aren't correct.

Comment: yeah, I'm on 14.1.3  Intelli-J itself worked and compiled and even ran my code, it's just when I had to restart my computer it suddenly stopped working.   How would the libraries mess up?

Comment: Why are you configuring module dependencies manually instead of using a tool such as `maven` ? Are you sure there is no `pom.xml` available for you to build off?

Comment: I have several pom.xml files.  And the dependencies I need off the internet auto-import just fine.  But the two dozen dependencies I need that my coworker wrote don't, and before he left he told me I'd have to manually import them.  I've checked them out of our git repo, mvn installed each individually...and it worked before...

Comment: Everyone should know how to do it without Maven. I'd recommend a clean checkout, removing the IntelliJ project files, and starting from scratch.

Comment: I've actually nuked the site from orbit, got everything fresh from git and redone the importing several times now.  The IntelliJ project files aren't stored in git, or anything... I don't have exactly the same problems every time, but it's always the same flavor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying the pom.xml eventually got it running. Not sure exactly what the problem was before, but at least I know the JUNIT weirdness was because I was labeling "src" in "src/main/java" as "source", but the test directory lived in "src/main/test", so it was confusing the compiler.